When I use a root terminal I can't type a dot as in 1.2
Installation on my PC: Debian 12 / Xfce
My problem is as a user the Xfce terminal works perfectly but as soon as I become root I can't type a dot (.) like in .bashrc or in 1.2. When I want to use the (.) key, nothing happens.
I have exactly the same problem if I use an SSH connection to connect to the PC: As a user it's okay, but as root I can't type 1.2.
What could be wrong with my installation? I don't even know where to start looking for a solution.
PS1: The root ls -a command can display a dot, root cannot.
PS2: as explained in a comment below, the problem was the .inputrc file. This file was a copy of the same one which is in my /home/ directory. I created a new one directly from the /root/ directory: it solved the problem.

Probably something in root's .inputrc. What's in that file?

not much: "\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
.inputrc lines 1-2/2 (END)

I commented (#) those 2 lines, sourced the new file but the problem is still there

I've deleted .inputrc, created a new .inputrc file and put back the contents, 2 lines, of the previous file. The problem is gone. Thanks to egmont
